# "Error during template rendering" in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 4 model classes (Course, Semester, Subject, TuModelQuestions) as you can see below. When I try to render particular question from TuModelQuestions from Particular Subject From Particular Semester And particular Course. How do I render it?

(Overall: I want to render that question only for particular subject, course and semester).

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelState

# Create your models here.
class Course(models.Model):
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Semester(models.Model):
    sem = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return F"Semester {self.sem} at Faculty {self.faculty}"


class Subject(models.Model):
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sem = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class TuModelQuestions(models.Model):
    date = models.IntegerField()
    model_question = models.ImageField(upload_to='imgs/')
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
from .forms import CustomerRegistrationForm
from .models import Course, Semester, Subject, TuModelQuestions

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'app/home.html')

def faculty(request):
    course = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/faculty.html', {'course':course})

class SemesterView(View):
    def get(self, request,id):
        obj = Course.objects.get(id=id)
        print(obj)
        semobj = Semester.objects.filter(faculty=obj)
        print(semobj)
        subobj = Subject.objects.filter(faculty=obj)
        print(subobj)
        return render(request, 'app/semester.html', {'obj':obj, 'semobj':semobj, 'subobj':subobj})


# =============SUBJECT================
def subject(request):
    return render(request, 'app/subject.html')

# =============MODEL QUESTIONS================
class ModelQuestions(View):
    def get(self,request,id):
        obj = Subject.objects.get(id=id)
        print(obj)
        model_question = TuModelQuestions.objects.filter(date=id)
        print(model_question)
        return render(request, 'app/model-questions.html',{'obj':obj, 'model_question':model_question})
```

**model-questions.html**

```
{% extends 'app/subject-base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block model-questions %}
    <div class="model-question">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">2070</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">2071</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">2072</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="questions-year">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="model-questions-box">
                        <img src="{% static 'app/image/tech.jpg' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
{% endblock model-questions %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, views as auth_views
from .forms import LoginForm


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
#     path('courses', views.CoursesView.as_view(), name='courses'),
     path('faculty', views.faculty, name="faculty"),
#     path('semester2', views.SemesterView.as_view(), name='semester2'),
    path('semester/<int:id>/', views.SemesterView.as_view(), name='semester'),
    path('subject', views.subject, name='subject'),
    path('model-questions/<int:id>/', views.ModelQuestions.as_view(), name='model-questions')
```

What I want is in this picture:

[image: click this image]

My error is:

[image: error picture]

Comment: Editor's note: this question has been heavily downvoted. I have reformatted the question, and added useful information to the title. If you can, please ask questions in this format, and they will be less likely to be downvoted. I have not voted.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provided, it seems like you're passing two keys in your `context` dictionary, these being `obj` and `model_question`. The problem is, you're not displaying them anywhere in your `model-questions.html` page. Your view seems okay, but your template is where the problem is.

In order to output the data you passed using `context`, try using the Django template syntax and output these two values.

Wherever you wish to, in your HTML template, add something like this:

```
{{ obj }}
```

or

```
{{ model_question }}
```

If you only want to see a particular field of these objects, you could try something like:

```
{{ obj.faculty }}
```

(...) given the fact that you have a field called `faculty` in your `Subject` model.

You should have provided your templates for the other fields, too, but you can do the same thing. If you're getting more than one object using, for example `modelName.objects.all()`, you can easily navigate through the items using a `for` loop in your `.html` template.

e.g. Imagine you're storing `modelName` into a context key called `models`. Now, what you can do in the `html` template would be something like that:

```
{% for model in models %}
   {{ model }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i have also provided the error pic. Can someone help me?

Comment: @UjjwolNeupane: please read this answer and apply it to your situation. Readers will not do your work for you. If you do not understand this answer or it does not work, you will need to explain what you do not understand or how it does not work.